# Which is the intermediate language used by PostgreSQL for query processing and optimization?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I'm currently doing a paper on PostgreSQL and I can't find anywhere (including their documentation) which is the intermediate language used for query processing and optimization.

Comment: The source code of the query parser should reveal that

Comment: The [tag:processing] tag should only be used for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I only used because there is no tag "query-processing" and I can't create one.

Comment: @mexzr If nobody is going to search for it you don't need a tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no intermediate "language" as such.

The SQL is parsed into a parse tree of `Node*`. This is then passed through the query rewriter, then transformed into a plan tree by the planner/optimizer. You can view these trees using the (documented) options `debug_print_parse`, `debug_print_rewritten` and `debug_print_plan`.

See the source code - `src/backend/parser/`, `src/backend/rewrite` and `src/backend/optimizer/` in particular, along with `src/include/nodes/nodes.h`, `plannodes.h`, `parsenodes.h`, etc. Note that there are `README` files in both the optimizer and parser source directories.

Comment: That's wierd because the report guidelines specify a sub-section of "Query processing and optimization" named "Intermediate language used". Anyway thanks for the answer I will definitly look into those references.

Comment: @mexzr "report guidelines"? Is this some kind of assignment?

Comment: Kind of, I'm supposed to study about the PostgreSQL and write a report about it. So I was studying the documentation and I noticed they don't talk about anything like "intermediate language" so I was intrigued about it. Is there any problem with asking this kind of questions?

Comment: No problem. It was just weirdly specific which is often a sign of possibly misundersood assignments.

Comment: So just to be certain you are 100% sure about your statement that there is no intermediate language right?

Comment: @mexzr Without knowing the exact definition of "intermediate language" used I cannot say. One might argue - weirdly - that the plantree and parsetree are an "intermediate language" at a stretch, and I've seen academics come up with much weirder things than that. Read thensource code and come to your own conclusions. I pointed out where to look.